# Oracle: show min and max consecutive code but adding check digit

Tags: sql, database, oracle, gaps-and-islands

I have the following Data

```
CUST_CODE DOC_PREFIX    DOC_NUMBER   DATE 
--------------------------------------------------
1111      001           1236         2019/01/01
1111      001           1249         2019/01/02
1111      001           1258         2019/01/03
1111      001           1268         2019/01/03
1111      002           1990         2019/02/15
1112      001           1118         2019/03/01
1112      003           1228         2019/03/01   
1112      003           1230         2019/03/01
1113      005           6666         2019/05/20
1114      002           6128         2019/10/01
1114      002           6138         2019/10/01
1114      002           6146         2019/10/01
1114      002           9916         2019/10/02
1114      002           9926         2019/10/02
```

DOC_NUMBER IS a key code + a check digit (1st example: 123 is the code 6 is the check digit)

i need grouped by CUST_CODE and DOC_PREFIX, show the MIN and MAX DOC_NUMBER only from consecutive numbers, but ordered by the code, and show the date from the MIN DOC_NUMBER

THIS IS WHAT I NEED:

```
CUST_CODE DOC_PREFIX    MIN_DOC_NUMBER   MAX_DOC_NUMBER   DATE 
--------------------------------------------------------------------
1111      001           1236             1268             2019/01/01
1111      002           1990             1990             2019/02/15
1112      001           1118             1118             2019/03/01
1112      003           1128             1130             2019/03/01
1113      005           6666             6666             2019/05/20
1114      002           6128             6146             2019/10/01
1114      002           9916             9926             2019/10/02
```

As you can see i have sort as follows :

```
CUST_CODE : 1111  = 123(6),124(9),125(8),126(8)
```

for this i have the next query:

```
WITH DOCNUMS AS (
    SELECT 
        CUST_CODE,
        DOC_PREFIX,
        DATE,
        DOC_NUMBER AS DOC,
        TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(DOC_NUMBER,1,LENGTH(DOC_NUMBER)-1)) AS DOC_NUMBER,
        TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(DOC_NUMBER,1,LENGTH(DOC_NUMBER)-1)) - ROW_NUMBER()
    over(
        ORDER BY 
            TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(DOC_NUMBER,1,LENGTH(DOC_NUMBER)-1))
        ) rn
    FROM 
        DOCS 
), ORDERDOCS AS (
    SELECT 
        DOCS.CUST_CODE,
        DOCS.DOC_PREFIX,
        MIN(DOCS.DOC_NUMBER) AS MIN_DOC,
        MAX(DOCS.DOC_NUMBER) AS MAX_DOC
    FROM 
        DOCNUMS DOCS
    GROUP BY    
        DOCS.CUST_CODE,DOCS.DOC_PREFIX,DOCS.rn
)   
    SELECT 
        DOCS.CUST_CODE,
        DOCS.DOC_PREFIX,
        DOCNUMS.DOC,
        (SELECT DOCNUMS.DOC FROM DOCNUMS WHERE DOCNUMS.CUST_CODE=DOCS.CUST_CODE AND DOCNUMS.DOC_NUMBER=DOCS.MAX_DOC),
        DOCNUMS.DATE
    FROM 
        ORDERDOCS DOCS
    INNER JOIN DOCNUMS
        ON DOCNUMS.CUST_CODE=DOCS.CUST_CODE
        AND DOCNUMS.DOC_NUMBER=DOCS.MIN_DOC
```

This works, buts its to slow, especially in the next part

```
DOCNUMS.DOC,
(SELECT DOCNUMS.DOC FROM DOCNUMS WHERE DOCNUMS.CUST_CODE=DOCS.CUST_CODE AND DOCNUMS.DOC_NUMBER=DOCS.MAX_DOC)
```

how can i get the Min and max code from doc_number but show the DOC_NUMBER with the check digit?

Comment: What is the datatype of column `DOC_NUMBER`?

Comment: Numeric, Integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a kind of gaps-and-island problem. Here is one way to solve it with a window sum:

```
select 
    cust_code, 
    doc_prefix, 
    min(doc_number) min_doc_number,
    max(doc_number) max_doc_number,
    min(doc_date) doc_date
from (
    select
        t.*,
        sum(case when floor(doc_number/10) = floor(lag_doc_number/10) + 1 then 0 else 1 end)
            over(partition by cust_code, doc_prefix order by doc_date) grp
    from (
        select
            t.*,
            lag(doc_number) 
                over(partition by cust_code, doc_prefix order by doc_date) lag_doc_number
        from mytable t
    ) t
) t
group by cust_code, doc_prefix, grp
order by cust_code, doc_prefix, grp
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=2828aa1d566d96cece41a143afffe303)**:

```
CUST_CODE | DOC_PREFIX | MIN_DOC_NUMBER | MAX_DOC_NUMBER | DOC_DATE  
--------: | ---------: | -------------: | -------------: | :---------
     1111 |          1 |           1236 |           1268 | 2019/01/01
     1111 |          2 |           1990 |           1990 | 2019/02/15
     1112 |          1 |           1118 |           1118 | 2019/03/01
     1112 |          3 |           1228 |           1230 | 2019/03/01
     1113 |          5 |           6666 |           6666 | 2019/05/20
     1114 |          2 |           6128 |           6146 | 2019/10/01
     1114 |          2 |           9916 |           9926 | 2019/10/02
```

**Explanation**:

- the most inner subquery recovers the value of the previous `doc_number` for the same `cust_code` and `doc_prefix`, ordered by `doc_date`
- the next subquery computes a window sum that defines the groups of records. To compare the `doc_number`s, we just divide them by 10 and drop the remainder part: when the resulting values are not sequential, then a new group starts
- the most outer query just aggregates within groups

Side note: `DATE` is not a sensible column name, I renamed it to `DOC_DATE` in the query and the fiddle.

Comment: @luchito: welcome! Ah yes, you are right about floor instead of round.